# Trying to run a websocket app through visual studio so I can debug it

Tags: websocket

I have run my regular http based app through visual studio and debug it without issue countless times. Today I am tasked with adding websocket support which I did.
My handler looks like this now:

```
public class ChatHandler : IHttpHandler


public bool IsReusable
{
  get { return false; }
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
  {
    context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessRequestInternal);
  }
  else
  {
    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
  }
}
```

My webconfig has a single catch all handler that points here and works fine for regular http requests.
However if I try to use websocket.org or my client to do a ws request to it(im avoiding wss because https is not setup on my local machine) the requests just time out and the above code is never reached (it is reached if i use a regular http request).

I googled for settings in applicationhost.config and found somebody listing a bunch of things from way back when that need to be added for websockets but the default applicationhost.config these days appears to have all these things.

Does anyone know what I might need to do to make IIS Express accept websocket requests?

All the web documentation is for when you have a machine actually running IIS and using server management to add websocket support however I don't have any of that since im simply running it from within visual studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the visual studio forum in case anyone else has this problem.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c553b7a5-0099-4488-aa89-0227a760b698/unable-to-host-a-websocket-based-app-using-iis-express?forum=vsdebug

Note that i had to use 53553 as my port because of the default config